# Regarding linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I am having difficulty in visualizing the transformation

$$z^{\prime}_1=az_1+bz_2$$

$$z^{\prime}_2=cz_1+dz_2$$

as a linear transformation. I am not sure   what's the input and  what is the output .  In other words, I don't get how this transformation works.

Kindly provide me some insight into it..

Thank you in advance

Comment: The input is (probably) the vector $(z_1,z_2)$ and the output is $(z_1',z_2')$

Answer (score 1):

It is the mapping $$\begin{pmatrix} z_1\\ z_2\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: What if I want single input..  single output

Comment: @AaqibIqbal The single input *is* the vector $(z_1,z_2)$ and the single output is $({z_1}',{z_2}')$.